# Ambisonic Recordings and RealityKit

Tags: audio, augmented-reality, realitykit

Will Realitykit support an ambisonic recording? I am planning on using binaural audio in an AR experience but it looks as if RealityKit doesnt support it.  Looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment RealityKit 2.0 doesn't support `Ambisonics`. It's hard to say whether it'll support it.

Comment: Hoping Unity isn't too heavy in its power consumption for our project.  Looks as if Apple has something in the works but only patent stage.